# How to make one user be able to comment more than one time by using firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a social media app, where user will be able to comment on different posts, I'm successfully uploading and receiveing comments from firebase when 1 user comments only one time. If one user comments 2 or more times the comment row just overrides the previous comment. Below is my database structure
[image]

Here is my code to send data to firebase:

```
private void sendComment() {
            final String message=myComment.getText().toString();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
            {
                DatabaseComment.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        DatabaseComment.child(mPostKey).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("comments").setValue(message);

                        hDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                DatabaseComment.child(mPostKey).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("othersName")
                                        .setValue(dataSnapshot.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("name").getValue());
                                DatabaseComment.child(mPostKey).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("othersDP")
                                        .setValue(dataSnapshot.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("DP").getValue());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

This is my Firebase Recycler Adapter in onStart method:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Profile,ProfileViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Profile, ProfileViewHolder>(

            Profile.class,
            R.layout.commentttt_row,
            ProfileViewHolder.class,
            DatabaseCommenttttt
    ) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final ProfileViewHolder viewHolder, final Profile model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setComments(model.getComments());
            viewHolder.setOthersName(model.getOthersName());
            viewHolder.setOthersDP(model.getOthersDP());
        }

    };

    mProfileList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mProfileList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

and this my ViewHolder Class:

```
public static class ProfileViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    View mView;

    LinearLayout mLinearName;
    TextView userName;
    TextView mComment;

    public ProfileViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView=itemView;

        userName=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_name);
        mLinearName=(LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.layout_name);
        mComment=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.comment);

    }

    public void setComments(String name)
    {
        TextView post_phone=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.others_comments);
        post_phone.setText(name);
    }
    public void setOthersName(String othersName) {
        TextView post_name=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.others_name);
        post_name.setText(othersName);
    }

    public void setOthersDP(String othersDP) {
        CircleImageView post_dp=(CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.othersaccountImageButton);
        if (!othersDP.equals("default"))
            Picasso.with(mView.getContext()).load(othersDP).into(post_dp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `post` structure is not quite good to do what you want and look the same. You should think to another one.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using `setvalue()` method in stead of using `updateChildren()` method. Because Firebase is a `JSON database` and is structured as paris of key and values, every node is a `Map`. So, in the case of `Map`, it replaces the old value with the new one.

To solve this, just use `updateChildren()` method in stead of `setvalue()` method. This is an example using a `HashMap`.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("/one-node/", oneStringValue);
map.put("/another-node/", anotherStringValue);
mDatabase.updateChildren(map);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but how can i pass a string into updatChildren method?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Note that `"/one-node/"` and `"/another-node/"` are the actual reference on which you need to update. `oneStringValue` and `anotherStringValue` are the actual values that needs to be updated.

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You should make another node inside of each user that commented. So the structure will be user key and then separate unique key per comment. Create a class that holds the comment and push that class inside of each individual user.

```
public class Comment() {
    String name;
    String othersDp;
    String dP;

   Comment(String n, String o, String d) {
       name = n;
       othersDp = o; 
       dP = d;
   }
}
```

Initialize those variables and push this class inside your database:

```
Comment newComment = new Comments("Hello","BLA","BLA");
DatabaseComment
    .child(mPostKey)
    .child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
    .child("othersName")
    .setValue(dataSnapshot.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
    .push()
    .setValue(newComments);
```

Comment: Comments ------>Post--------->User-------->UniqueCommentKey----->comment

Comment: When you use push() as wrote in the code, Firebase automatically generates a unique key for that node

Comment: So if you push each comment, each comment will have a unique key so it won't override your previous comments

Comment: but how will i fetch the data in firebase recycler adapter if i dont know what is the value of pushed key? is there any way we can get to know the pushed key?

Comment: hey, when i use push, it creates infinite amount of child under a node.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set a listener to your database.

```
Arraylist<Comment> commentArray = new ArrayList<Comment>();
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.child("Comments").child(Userid).getChildren()) {
    Comment individualComment = postSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
    commentArray.add(individualComment);
}
```

This code will loop is supposed to loop through each comment and will save each comment node in the Comment class and save them into ArrayList

Comment: i have put this code in hDatabase,addValueEventListener, but after debugging it says commentArray size =0

Comment: I'm new to this thing, so sorry if my questions are annoying you. Your help will be highly appreciated.